# Edit every even-indexed element in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm pretty new to lisp and I want to make function that every even-indexed element replace it with new one element list that holds this element. For example

> (1 2 3 4 5) -> (1 (2) 3 (4) 5), (1 2 3 4 5 6) -> (1 (2) 3 (4) 5 (6))

Right now I came up with solution that each of the lements put in it's own list, but I cant get exactly how to select every even-indexed element:

```
(DEFUN ON3 (lst)
 ((ATOM (CDR lst)) (CONS (CONS (CAR lst) NIL) NIL))
 (CONS (CONS (CAR lst) NIL) (ON3 (CDR lst))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work. You'll need to use `if` or `cond` such that the code follow one of the paths in it. Right now you have an error truing to call a function called `(atom (cdr lst))`. If it had been something that worked it would be dead code because the next line is always run regardless. It is infinite recursion.

So how to count. You can treat every step as a handle on 2 elements at a time. You need to take care of the following:

```
(enc-odds '())         ; ==> ()
(enc-odds '(1))        ; ==> (1)
(enc-odds '(1 2 3 ...) ; ==> (1 (2) (enc-odds (3 ...))
```

Another way is to make a helper with extra arguments:

```
(defun index-elements (lst)
  (labels ((helper (lst n)
             (if (null lst)
                 lst
                 (cons (list (car lst) n)
                       (helper (cdr lst) (1+ n))))))
    (helper lst 0)))
(index-elements '(a b c d))
; ==> ((a 0) (b 1) (c 2) (d 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

For a non-recursive solution, loop allows for constructing simultaneous iterators:

```
(defun every-second (list)
  (loop
      for a in list
      for i upfrom 1
      if (evenp i) collect (list a)
      else collect a))

(every-second '(a b c d e))
; ==> (A (B) C (D) E)
```

See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html for a nice explanation of loop